# mutate_each on tidyr nested table gives "Unknown inputs"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I am trying to do a `mutate_each` using `purr::map` on a group of tables created by `tidyr::nest`.

Below is an example of what I am trying to do and the resulting error:

```
library(tidyr)
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


by_country <- gapminder %>% 
  group_by(continent, country) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data2 = map(data,  ~ mutate_each(.,funs(as.numeric))))
```

gives:

`Error: Unknown inputs`

What is causing this problem? Is there a fix? I could use `apply` instead of `mutate_each` but that removes rownames.

**EDIT:** From the first response it seems the purpose was not clear. So perhaps I am trying to do something the wrong way. Let me explain.

If you do:

```
by_country <- gapminder %>% 
   group_by(continent, country) %>% 
   nest()
```

You have:

```
by_country$data[[1]]
Source: local data frame [12 x 4]

    year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
   (int)   (dbl)    (int)     (dbl)
1   1952  28.801  8425333  779.4453
2   1957  30.332  9240934  820.8530
3   1962  31.997 10267083  853.1007
4   1967  34.020 11537966  836.1971
5   1972  36.088 13079460  739.9811
6   1977  38.438 14880372  786.1134
7   1982  39.854 12881816  978.0114
8   1987  40.822 13867957  852.3959
9   1992  41.674 16317921  649.3414
10  1997  41.763 22227415  635.3414
11  2002  42.129 25268405  726.7341
12  2007  43.828 31889923  974.5803
```

What I would like is run a function for each column; but done separately for each nested table. So I would like to run the equevalent of the below on each table:

```
mutate_each(by_country$data[[1]],funs(as.numeric))
```

Giving:

```
Source: local data frame [12 x 4]

    year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
   (dbl)   (dbl)    (dbl)     (dbl)
1   1952  28.801  8425333  779.4453
2   1957  30.332  9240934  820.8530
3   1962  31.997 10267083  853.1007
4   1967  34.020 11537966  836.1971
5   1972  36.088 13079460  739.9811
6   1977  38.438 14880372  786.1134
7   1982  39.854 12881816  978.0114
8   1987  40.822 13867957  852.3959
9   1992  41.674 16317921  649.3414
10  1997  41.763 22227415  635.3414
11  2002  42.129 25268405  726.7341
12  2007  43.828 31889923  974.5803
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps show the expected output given the `gapminder` data frame as input?

Comment: OK. Updated the question.

Comment: Why not do this: `gapminder %>% mutate_each_(funs(as.numeric), names(gapminder)[sapply(gapminder, is.integer)]) %>% group_by(country, continent) %>% nest()`?

Comment: Only because I need to run the mutate_each on nested data. In the example it doesn't matter but with what I am trying to do it needs to be on the nested data. I have changed the shape of each nested table so it cannot be un-nested to do the mutate_each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` uses `.x` to reference the input data when the function argument is given as a formula.  After that change, there are two possibilities for the form of `mutate_each` :

```
by_country <- gapminder %>% 
  group_by(continent, country) %>% 
  nest()  %>%
  mutate(data2 = map(data,  ~ mutate_each(.x, "as.numeric")))
```

or

```
by_country2 <- gapminder %>% 
  group_by(continent, country) %>% 
  nest()  %>%
  mutate(data2 = map(data,  ~ mutate_each(.x, funs(as.numeric(.)))))
```

It seems that `mutate(data2 = map(data,  ~ mutate_each(.x, funs(as.numeric))))`  should also work but it doesn't.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much.